# Cannot implicitly convert type IAsyncOperation<StorageFile> to StorageFile

Tags: c#, microsoft-metro, async-await, filepicker, storagefile

What the hell is wrong with my code?

```
    private void BrowseButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        FileOpenPicker FilePicker = new FileOpenPicker();
        FilePicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".exe");
        FilePicker.ViewMode = PickerViewMode.List;
        FilePicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.Desktop;
        // IF I PUT AWAIT HERE   V     I GET ANOTHER ERROR¹
        StorageFile file = FilePicker.PickSingleFileAsync();
        if (file != null)
        {
            AppPath.Text = file.Name;
        }
        else
        {
            AppPath.Text = "";
        }         
    }
```

It gives me this error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'Windows.Foundation.IAsyncOperation' to 'Windows.Storage.StorageFile'

And if I add the 'await', like commented on the code, I get the following error:

> ¹ The 'await' operator can only be used within an async method. Consider marking this method with the 'async' modifier and changing its return type to 'Task'.

Code source [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/BR207847)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, the reason your code doesn't compile is explained pretty directly by the compiler error message. [`FileOpenPicker.PickSingleFileAsync`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br207852.aspx) returns an `IAsyncOperation<StorageFile>` - so no, you can't assign that return value to a `StorageFile` variable. The typical way of using `IAsyncOperation<>` in C# is with `await`.

You can only use `await` in `async` methods... so you probably want to change your method to be asynchronous:

```
private async void BrowseButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ...
    StorageFile file = await FilePicker.PickSingleFileAsync();
    ...
}
```

Note that for anything other than event handlers, it's better to make an async method return `Task` rather than `void` - the ability to use `void` is really only so you *can* use an async method as an event handler.

If you're not really familiar with `async`/`await` yet, you should probably read up on it before you go any further - the [MSDN "Asynchronous Programming with async and await"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh191443.aspx) page is probably a decent starting point.

Comment: Now I get it, thanks very much! I'm starting to learn C# and this async/await stuff is really new to me.
Your help is very appreciated!