# Can't convert type IAsyncOperation<BluetoothDevice> to BluetoothDevice

Tags: c#, winforms, bluetooth

I'm trying to get a `BluetoothDevice` from its address.
When I try this:

```
// type of e is BluetoothLEAdvertisementReceivedEventArgs
BluetoothDevice device = BluetoothDevice.FromBluetoothAddressAsync(e.BluetoothAddress);
```

I get this error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type "Windows.Foundation.IAsyncOperation<Windows.Devices.Bluetooth.BluetoothDevice>" to "Windows.Devices.Bluetooth.BluetoothDevice"

In a [similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16512378/14448817) someone recommended to use a async method with await.
So I tried this:

```
private async void NewDeviceDetected(BluetoothLEAdvertisementReceivedEventArgs e)
{
   if (InvokeRequired)
   {
      this.Invoke(new Action(() => NewDeviceDetected(e)));
      return;
   }

   //Get Device
   BluetoothDevice device = await BluetoothDevice.FromBluetoothAddressAsync(e.BluetoothAddress);
}
```

but now I'm getting this error:

> 'IAsyncOperation<BluetoothDevice>' does not contain a definition for
> 'GetAwaiter' and no extension method 'GetAwaiter' accepting a first
> argument of type 'IAsyncOperation<BluetoothDevice>' could be found
> (are you missing a using directive for 'System'?)

I am `using System;`

Comment: Well - your code looks fine, you should indeed use await - like the docs say: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/threading-async/call-asynchronous-apis-in-csharp-or-visual-basic#return-types-and-results-of-asynchronous-apis . Have you checked this SO out? See if that is the issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44099401/frombluetoothaddressasync-iasyncoperation-does-not-contain-a-definition-for-get

Comment: @sommmen I was missing a reference to WindowsRuntime.dll . Thanks for the help!

Comment: ^^ `IAsyncOperation` doesn't have it's own `GetAwaiter()` method; it comes as an extension in WindowsRuntime.dll